# Postgres - Cohort analysis across months sequentially, not if exists in any later month

Tags: sql, postgresql, cluster-analysis, analytics

I'm doing a cohort analysis and can get the group of users to examine, then see whether they transacted in the months following on. But I want it like this:

Of that group in December, who transacted in Jan; of the Jan group from Dec, who transacted in Feb. Basically i'm tracking decay of the customer base

What I don't want is those that return in any month following Dec, which is this:

```
WITH start_sample AS (
SELECT
  user_fk,
  created_at AS start_sample_date
  FROM transactions
    WHERE created_at >= '2016-11-01' AND created_at < '2016-12-01'
      GROUP BY user_fk,
        start_sample_date),

start_sample_min AS (
SELECT
  user_fk,
  MIN(start_sample_date) AS first_transaction
    FROM start_sample
      GROUP BY user_fk
  )

SELECT
  DATE_TRUNC('month', created_at) AS transacting_month,
  COUNT(DISTINCT user_fk)
    FROM transactions
        WHERE created_at >= '2016-11-01'
        AND t.user_fk IN(SELECT user_fk FROM start_sample_min)
          GROUP BY transacting_month
            ORDER BY transacting_month;
```

Then I made a churn model to see if it would get what I need, but it doesn't:

```
WITH monthly_users AS (
    SELECT
      user_fk AS monthly_user_fk,
      DATE_TRUNC('month', created_at) AS month
        FROM transactions
          WHERE created_at >= '2016-11-01' AND created_at < '2017-12-01'
            GROUP BY monthly_user_fk, month
            ORDER BY monthly_user_fk, month
),

lag_lead AS (
  SELECT
    monthly_user_fk,
    month,
    LAG(month,1) OVER (PARTITION BY monthly_user_fk ORDER BY month) AS lag,
    LEAD(month,1) OVER (PARTITION BY monthly_user_fk ORDER BY month) AS lead
      FROM monthly_users),

lag_lead_with_diffs AS (
  SELECT
    monthly_user_fk,
    month,
    lag AS previous_month,
    lead AS next_month,
    EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (month - lag)/86400)::INT AS lag_size,
    EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (lead - month)/86400)::INT AS lead_size
      FROM lag_lead
  ),

calculated AS (
      SELECT
      month,
      CASE WHEN previous_month IS NULL THEN 'ACTIVATION'
          WHEN lag_size <= 31 THEN 'ACTIVE'
          WHEN lag_size > 31 THEN 'RETURN' END AS this_month_values,
      CASE WHEN (lead_size > 31 OR lead_size IS NULL) THEN 'CHURN' ELSE NULL END AS next_month_churn,
      COUNT(DISTINCT monthly_user_fk) AS c_d_users
   FROM lag_lead_with_diffs
  GROUP BY month, 2, 3
)

SELECT
  month,
  this_month_values,
  SUM(c_d_users) AS distinct_users
  FROM calculated
  GROUP BY month, this_month_values
UNION
SELECT month + INTERVAL '1 month',
  'CHURN',
  SUM(c_d_users)
  FROM calculated
    WHERE next_month_churn IS NOT NULL
      GROUP BY month + INTERVAL '1 month', 2
        HAVING (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (month + INTERVAL '1 month'))) < 1512086400
          ORDER BY month, this_month_values;
```

However this is not fixed at the initial group. The Active group rolls from month to month.

I understand that the above is likely more complicated than what i'm asking, but I can't seem to get my head around it

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for:

```
with Monthly_Users as (
select user_fk
     , date_trunc('month',created_at) as month
     , (date_part('year', created_at) - 2016) * 12
     + date_part('month', created_at) - 11 as Months_Between
  from transactions
 where created_at between date '2016-11-01'
                      and date '2017-12-01'
 group by user_fk, month, months_between
), t2 as (
select Monthly_Users.*
     , count(*) over (partition by user_fk
                          order by month rows between unbounded preceding
                                                  and 1 preceding) prev_rec_cnt
  from Monthly_Users
)
select month
     , count(*)
  from t2
 where Months_Between = Prev_Rec_Cnt
 group by month
 order by month;
```

In this query the `Monthly_Users` CTE is just like yours, but adds a computation of the number of `Months_Between` the `created_at` date and your initial starting date.  In the second Common Table Expression, I count the number of occurrences of each user_fk prior to the current `month`s record.  Finally in the output query I limit the results to only those records where the `Months_Between` value matches the `Prev_Rec_Cnt` value. Any missed months will cause the `Prev_Rec_Cnt` value to not match the `Months_Between` value, so you'll be able to see the fall off of user_fk values from month to month.

Comment: That's really great, exactly what I needed. Thank you

Comment: Would you mind helping me with the line 'months between' line? Why do you do 2017 - 2016 * 12 -11? I'm trying to convert it to do weeks as well

Comment: Just had a brainwave, you must take the week number that the dataset starts from. Nevermind, thanks again. If anyone is interested it's      , (DATE_PART('year', created_at) - 2016) * 52 + DATE_PART('week', created_at) - 45 AS weeks_between

Comment: Yes you got it.  postgreSQL unfortunately doesn't have a native datediff function, so you have to roll your own using the date_part functions.